# Firejail and chrome: limiting RAM useage

Tags: memory, chromium, memory-leaks, firejail, v8

Long story short, I have a consistent memory leak coming from somewhere. I'm thinking that it's my browser. So I've tried using `firejail` to limit the memory as follows:

`firejail --rlimit-as=8048576000 vivaldi-stable`

Which limits the RAM usage (as I understand) to 8GB, which is a huge amount.

And I get this error.

> Fatal error in , line 0
> Fatal process out of memory: Failed to reserve memory for new V8 Isolate
> FailureMessage Object: 0x7ffc6d28e0c0#0 0x557c2240ec09

Now if I increase the `--rlimit-as` by one more GB, `vivaldi` boots up fine.

Same thing happens if I try to start `chromium` process.

Question: why does V8 need to reserve 9GB of memory? Why so much? Is there any way I can lower that?

**Edit:**
Some more googling, and I stumbled upon this method that works fine:
 `systemd-run --scope --user -p  MemoryLimit=1G vivaldi-stable`

PS. I'm running Arch linux with 20GB of ram

Comment: Read `man 1 firejail` where `--rlimit-as` refers to the *virtual* memory. Then read [*What is virtual memory?*](https://superuser.com/q/42854/432690)

Comment: ^ that should be the accepted answer.